# google map V2 key

Tags: google-maps-api-2

Now I have a "Google Maps API V2" for site use. I would like to change a domain name, but the previous place applying for V2 security keys is no longer available, and it would take some time if I'm to upgrade site to V3.
  So would you inform me a new URL where I can apply for V2 security keys, or are there any other solutions?

my domain name: http://www.icar168.cn

thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

They are no longer "required" but you can create/register for one a [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?pli=1).

Just click the link, select your sevice by clicking "on" and then click API access and you will see your key.